# Parse error in pip: "'-e git+h'": Expected W:(abcd...)

Tags: python, pip

I have a private python package, `hidden`. In that package, I'd like to use another private package of mine, `zempy`.

In hidden's requirements, there is a line

```
git+https://gitlab.com/group/zempy.git@0.4.7#egg=zempy
```

...which I've also tried writing as:

```
-e git+https://gitlab.com/group/zempy.git@0.4.7#egg=zempy
```

And I'm installing hidden with `python3 -m pip install .` or `python3 -m pip install -e .` (in hidden's main directory)

But I got an error:

> error in hiddenco setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Parse error at "'-e git+h'": Expected W:(abcd...)

This seemed like working before. Suddenly it stopped working. Anyone has an idea? I have tried nearly everything in that requirements line. It's installing without that line. But I need zempy in hidden.

I have double checked install_requires parameter in setup. It is a list of string.

The `setup.py` in hidden:

```py
"""Setuptools for hidden package."""
from glob import glob
from os.path import basename, splitext

import setuptools
from setuptools import setup


def readme():
    """Return readme as string."""
    with (open('README.md')) as f:
        return f.read()


def get_requirements():
    """
    Return requirements as list.

    package1==1.0.3
    package2==0.0.5
    """
    with open('requirements.txt') as f:
        return [line.replace('\n', '') for line in f.readlines()]


setup(
    name='hiddenco',
    long_description=readme(),
    packages=setuptools.find_packages('src'),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    install_requires=get_requirements(),
    py_modules=[splitext(basename(path))[0] for path in glob('src/*.py')],
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    python_requires='>=3.6, !=3.9.*, !=3.10.*'
)
```

And the `requirements.txt`:

```
coloredlogs
pymongo >=3.7.2
fasttext==0.9.2
pytest >=6.1.2
pandas <=1.5.0
numpy >=1.16.1, <=1.19.5
-e git+https://gitlab.com/group/zempy.git@0.4.7#egg=zempy
```

Comment: The error message is talking about `install_requires` in the `setup.py`, not about the `requirements.txt` file. We need to see the `setup.py` contents.

Comment: Yes, it's saying that it "must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers". I have verified that it's a list of strings. Where else should I check?

Comment: Please provide a `setup.py` that reproduces the problem when run without changes so people other than you can check (and so that people can verify answers).

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: Thank you -- this looks complete enough to be answerable now.

Comment: Thanks. I thought this is hard to reproduce because it requires a private repo. Glad if it helped.

Answer (score 4):

Your `get_requirements` function needs to return just a list of package names and (optional) versions. `install_requires` merely documents which packages and versions are required; it does not support specifying where or how to obtain them.

A quick and dirty fix is to just discard the extra information you crammed in there.

```py
def get_requirements():
    """
    Return requirements as list.

    package1==1.0.3
    package2==0.0.5
    """
    with open('requirements.txt') as f:
        packages = []
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            # let's also ignore empty lines and comments
            if not line or line.startswith('#'):
                continue
            if 'https://' in line:
                tail = line.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
                tail = tail.split('#')[0]
                line = tail.replace('@', '==').replace('.git', '')
            packages.append(line)
    return packages
```

This pulls out `.../zempy.git@0.4.7` and converts it to `zempy==0.4.7`.

Comment: So maybe do I need to explicitly document it and/or maybe print a warning when hidden is imported, that `zempy` should be installed and it can be installed with *bla bla*?

Comment: I'll remove it from requirements.txt and except ImportError when needed. I think this is the most intuitive way.

Comment: If the package is not installed, attempting to `import` it will already fail quite trivially and with a good error message, so probably don't explicitly do anything then. The _proper_ solution going forward is to use a `pyproject.toml` file for your build requirements but I don't know how to use that for your specific use case.

Comment: Yea you are right. I just wanted to message how to install it without asking to anyone :) Thank you for the support.

Comment: I still think putting it in your `requirements.txt` and using this code to parse it is probably the best quick fix. Then you can still expect `pip install -r requirements.txt` to _do what you want_ **and** have a correct `setup.py`.

Comment: But your solution still fails even if zempy is installed. Is that what you really meant to do? Edit: Ah, I had to remove the *.git* part and it worked if it's installed.

Comment: Fails how? The things I can replicate work fine for me here. Does `zempy` have a valid `setup.py` etc?

Comment: I think it's because `zempy` is a private repo too. I mean with your solution it tries to install something like `zempy.git` but it's not a public pypi package; it's private.

Comment: If you have read access to it, `pip` can find it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238871/discussion-between-emremrah-and-tripleee).